# Referencing an excel file with previous month as name to paste data into it with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for the VBA code to reference an excel file which has the previous months as it's name.

I have tried the below code, which creates the file from a template & saves it with the previous months name no problem. I then try to reference this file in order to paste some values into it, but I keep getting Runtime Error 9: Subscript out of range.

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="https://X.sharepoint.com/GROUP/Whiteboard/Malton%20New%20Month%20Template.xlsx?web=1"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="https://X.sharepoint.com/GROUP/Whiteboard/2022/Malton/Malton " & Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "mmm yyyy"), FileFormat:=51, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
, CreateBackup:=False

Workbooks("WHITEBOARD project.xlsm").Worksheets("Malton Weekly Input").Range("A5:R404").Copy

Workbooks("Malton " & Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "mmm yyyy" & "xlsx")).Worksheets("Data").Range("AC5:AT404").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Allan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file naming is not consistent, but if you get a reference to the file when you first open it, you don't need to refer to it by name.

```vb
Sub tester()
    
    Const ROOT As String = "https://X.sharepoint.com/GROUP/Whiteboard/"
    
    Dim prevMnth As String, wb As Workbook
    
    'get a reference when you open the file...
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ROOT & "Malton%20New%20Month%20Template.xlsx?web=1")
    
    prevMnth = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "mmm yyyy")
    
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=ROOT & "2022/Malton/Malton " & prevMnth & ".xlsx", _
              FileFormat:=51, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
              ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

    Workbooks("WHITEBOARD project.xlsm").Worksheets("Malton Weekly Input").Range("A5:R404").Copy
    
    wb.Worksheets("Data").Range("AC5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
End Sub
```